# How to run a whole js files multiple times using duk_pcall?

Tags: duktape

I want to use `duk_pcall` to do it, here is what I tried:

- Firstly, I load the script file into a `char* string`.
- Secondly, use `duk_pcompile_string(ctx, 0, programBody)` to compile it.
- Then, I can use `duk_pcall(ctx, 0)` to call it once, and call `duk_pop(ctx)`.

But when I try to use `duk_pcall` a second time, I failed.

Can you give me some advice about how to do it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`duk_pcompile_string` places the result on the TOS and `duk_pcall` executes the TOS (+ eventual parameters) and replaces all of that by the return value of the call.

In order to make the function callable multiple times you have to [duplicate the TOS](https://duktape.org/api.html#duk_dup_top) insert the required parameter and then call that using the pcall. After the call remove the result from the stack. The original function should now be at the TOS again. Start over with what is written in this paragraph, to call it again.

Comment: I just want to compile once and run it multiple times, is that possible? I've searched here, and found : using duk_get_global_string , we can compile once and call a JS function multiple times with duk_pcall.

Comment: Sure, just duplicate the TOS before you call `duk_pcall`. You should have the compile module still on the stack then and on next call you duplicate again, to always keep a copy of the original script.

Comment: Sorry, I just can‘t’ figure out how to duplicate the TOS. I've tried to use `duk_dump_function(ctx)` with `duk_load_function(ctx)` and found it can only run once. Could you tell me how to duplicate the TOS and recover TOS each time?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully this clears things for you.